# Should I call this an escaping issue in HTML and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, escaping

Excuse me, how could I possible do something like this?

I have a DIV, which I hoped to use like a button to switch displaying content. When visitor touch it, the SPAN in the P will toggle. But I found the following problem. Please help me.

```
<div id="some_id" onclick="jQ_hide('.some_class p[class^="xxx-yyy"] span:nth-child(1)');"></div>
<div id="someother_id" onclick="jQ_show('.some_class p[class^="xxx-yyy"] span:nth-child(2)');"></div>
```

jQ_hide and jQ_show is function to hide and show lots element in a time.

I don't know what to do when a " happens in 2 "s .

Sorry for my bad English. Thank you.

Edit:

I have lots of .xxx-yyy-1 , .xxx-yyy-2, .xxx-yyy-3 ... so I need to do this, or any other solution?

Edit 2:

I do not use jQuery .toggle is because .toggle takes time.

Thank you.

Comment: #1 don't mix JS and HTML, #2 HTML escape attribute values.

Comment: `I do not use jQuery .toggle is because .toggle takes time.`  It might take time, but it's better to work harder and do it the right way, than to cut corners.

Comment: You don't delete questions on SO (unless you're a moderator) -- you leave them up for posterity. Please put your original question and tags back and [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/171394) from the ones provided to you.

Comment: You don't delete questions once they're answered.  Just leave it here for the next person who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your inner double-quotes with escaped single quotes `\'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="some_id" onclick="jQ_hide('.some_class p[class^=\'xxx-yyy\'] span:nth-child(1)');"></div>
<div id="someother_id" onclick="jQ_show('.some_class p[class^=\'xxx-yyy\'] span:nth-child(2)');"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an issue with the escaping of your quotes within the onclick attribute of the element.  I would suggest that you apply these functions differently however.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function jQ_hide() { ... }
    function jQ_show() { ... }

    $("#some_id").on("click", jQ_hide);
    $("#someother_id").on("click", jQ_show);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to write a seperate method to hide and show `<P>`, you can just write `$('.PClassName').show()` to show and `$('.PClassName').hide()` to hide the P.